# How to clean up class member of pointer to vector of pointers to a class?

Tags: c++

I have a class called Foo which has a member that is a pointer to a vector of pointers to another class called Bar. I initialise it in the constructor but I'm not sure how to deallocate it in the destructor. I'm still learning. Would appreciate your help. The reason for having this member is so that the scope persists beyond that method i.e. beyond the stack. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Bar {};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        bars = new vector<Bar*>*[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            bars[i]->push_back(new Bar());
        }
    }

    ~Foo () {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // TODO: how to clean up bars properly?
        }
    }

private:
    vector<Bar*>** bars;
};

int main () {
    new Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**: I appreciate the feedback on all fronts. I'm new to C and C++. Basically I wanted a 2d structure as a class member that would persist for the lifetime of the class. The reason the outer structure is an array is because I know how big it needs to be. Otherwise I was previously using vector of vectors.

Comment: `vector<Bar*> bars;` will exist for the lifetime of `Foo`. `vector<unique_ptr<Bar>> bars;` or `vector<shared_ptr<Bar>> bars;` makes life easier again.

Comment: `vector<Bar*>** bars;` Holy cow!

Comment: haha i think it's a typo according to his description

Comment: @AK4749 No, if you look at how he allocates, it's not a typo.

Comment: It's not a good thing to be a three-star programmer. Also: if you really want to use pointers, use smart pointers. You can't really mess up with std::shared_ptr

Comment: Just make the member variable either a `vector<vector<Bar>>` or a `vector<vector<unique_ptr<Bar>>>` this mix of arrays, vectors and pointers is crazy and error prone.

Comment: "The reason for having this [pointer] is so that the scope persists beyond that method i.e. beyond the stack" Understood. The good news is that `std::vector` has an assignment operator that will allow you copy the contents to member `bars` before the original goes out of scope; no need for a pointer to `vector`.

Comment: From what I see, I don't think you've noticed that C++ doesn't have to use `new` for every single allocation. In fact, the use of `new` should be limited to creating/resetting smart pointers.

Comment: You say you want "the scope to persist beyond the method." But, `bars` is a private member, and you're not returning it like you might in a factory. Also, you're also trying to delete it. Could you explain what you're trying to do in a bit more detail?

Comment: Thanks all. I'm still learning C/C++. Basically all I want is a 2d structure containing Bar. I know how big the outer dimension has to be, let's say, 10. But the inner structures I don't know the size of. So I created an array of vectors. The way I've done it was suggested by someone else who's more experienced. It did seem a little overcomplicated to me too.

Comment: @junkie if you want a fixed known size use a regular array (or `std::array`) **not `new`**. (Also, `std::vector<blah>(10)` creates a vector with a known size). There's zero reason to use `new` here (hint: `new` is a very specialized tool; it's not useful for most common scenarios)

Comment: @junkie, If what I got from that comment is right, `std::array<std::vector<Bar>, 10> bars;` would make an array of 10 dynamic arrays of `Bar`.

Comment: @chris Thanks. The 10 value is passed into the constructor of the class. Sorry example should have shown this. How do I declare this member in private but initialise it in the constructor with a size that's passed in to the constructor?

Comment: @junkie, So the outer size depends on the argument. `std::vector<std::vector<Bar>> bars;` would do it, though a wrapper around a 1D version would perform better, and in the ctor, all youd have to do to initialize the outer one with size n passed in is `Foo(int n) : bars(n){...}`

Comment: @chris And how do I initialise each internal vector within bars? By using `new vector<Bar>`?

Comment: @junkie, C++ doesn't require `new` to allocate something. To resize it, just use `bars[i].resize()`. To add an element onto the back, use `push_back()` or `emplace_back()`. Best to look up a reference on vectors to find what suits your situation.

Comment: @chris Can you please post your suggestion of using `std::vector<std::vector<Bar>> bars;` as an answer so I can accept it? That's what I ended up using and it worked. I gave up trying to get the three star horror to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of pointers is a bit ridiculous, as all they are doing is causing confusion and leaks, as evident from non-proper initialization and the question's title. You don't actually need any pointers at all, and don't have to worry about any cleanup.

For a 2D array with the first dimension passed into the constructor, you can use a vector of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Bar>> bars;
```

To initialize the outer vector with the passed in size, use an initializer:

```
Foo(size_t size) 
    : bars(size) {}
```

When the object is destroyed, `bars` and all of it elements are as well, so there's no chance of forgetting to clean up or doing so improperly.

If performance is an issue, this can be translated into a sort of `Matrix2D` class that acts like a 2D array, but really only has an underlying 1D array.

Comment: Thanks Chris. One last thing. I actually used this with one difference: I used Bar* and was adding objects into the vector by doing new Bar(...). How do I instantiate a Bar with constructor args in a way that doesn't give me back a pointer as in your suggestion? I'm still very new to all this. (Obviously if I was using Bar* I would have to delete them accordingly).

Comment: @junkie, If you want to push an item on the back, you can use `push_back`. Your way would look something like `bars[0].push_back(new Bar(5));`, whereas a non-pointer version might look like `bars[0].push_back(Bar(5));`.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't even allocated properly. You allocate an array of pointers to `std::vector<Bar*>`, but never any `std::Vector<Bar*>`.

The best thing to do is just something like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>>` or even `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>>>` or something like that. What you've got is just WTF.

Or `std::unique_ptr<std::array<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>>>, 10>>`.This is an exact match (but self-cleaning).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: In the case of a 2D structure (and you said you know how big your 2D structure needs to be, so we'll assume that the 10 in your loops is the size of the 2D array you desire.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Bar {
public:
    int BarInfo;
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        // Allocates 10 vector spots for 10 bar elements - 100 bars, 10 x 10
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // Puts 10 bars pointer at the end;
            // Heap-allocated (dynamically), which
            // means it survives until you delete it
            // The [10] is array syntax, meaning you'll have 10 bars
            // for each bars[index] and then
            // you can access it by bars[index][0-9]
            // If you need it to be more dynamic
            // then you should try vector<vector<Bar>>
            bars.push_back(new Bar[10]);
        }
    }

    Bar* operator[] (int index) {
        return bars[index];
    }

    ~Foo () {
        // Cleanup, because you have pointers inside the vector,
        // Must be done one at a time for each element
        for (int i = 0; i < bars.size(); i++) {
            // TODO: how to clean up bars properly?
            // Each spot in the vector<> contains 10 bars,
            // so you use the array deletion
            // and not just regular 'delete'
            delete[] bars[i]; // deletes the 10 array elements
        }
    }

private:
    // vector might not be a bad idea.
    vector<Bar*> bars;
};
```

This is the main I have for testing the code written, and it works like you would think a 2D array should work:

```
int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    Foo foo;
    // Bar at 1st row, 2nd column ( row index 0, column index 1 )
    // Bar& is a reference
    Bar& bar12 = foo[0][1];
    bar12.BarInfo = 25;
    int stuffInsideBar = foo[0][1].BarInfo; // 25
    return 0;
}
```

I hope that helps and gets you closer to what you're doing. I've used a technique here that might go over a starters head to make the `Foo` class behave like you would think a 2D array would. It's called [operator overloading](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/). It's a powerful feature in C++, so once you master more basics it might be useful to you in your future projects or current one. Good luck!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

OLD ANSWER BEFORE EDIT

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

It appears you're doing far too much indirection. While another person's answer shows you how to clean up what you've managed to do, I think you could benefit from changing how exactly you're handling the class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Bar {};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : bars() {
        // bars is no longer a pointer-to-vectors, so you can just
        // allocate it in the constructor - see bars() after Foo()
        //bars = new vector<Bar>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // Puts 1 bar pointer at the end;
            // Heap-allocated (dynamically), which
            // means it survives until you delete it
            bars.push_back(new Bar());
        }
    }

    ~Foo () {
        // Cleanup, because you have pointers inside the vector,
        // Must be done one at a time for each element
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // TODO: how to clean up bars properly?
            // TODOING: One at a time
            delete bars[i]; // deletes pointer at i
        }
    }

private:
    // You don't need to ** the vector<>,
    // because it's inside the class and 
    // will survive for as long as the class does
    // This vector will also be copied to copies of Foo,
    // but the pointers will remain the same at the time
    // of copying.
    // Keep in mind, if you want to share the vector, than
    // making it a std::shared_ptr of a
    // vector might not be a bad idea.
    vector<Bar*> bars;
};
```

If you pass the class by reference into functions, than the `vector<Bar*>` inside the class won't copy itself or delete itself, making it persist past a single stack frame.

In your `main`, this should clean up properly and is a lot easier to keep track of than vector** . However, if for some reason vector** is required, than home_monkey's answer should help you more.

Comment: Thanks. However, sorry I should have said in my original post, I'm looking for a 2d structure not 1d. I have elaborated in an update to my original post and in post comments.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a clear example of what I think the OP wants. Let me know if it's not correct.

Comment: Thanks again. I know the size of my outer dimension but not the inner.

Comment: @junkie Then it would probably be best for you to have it in the configuration of `std::array<vector<Bar>, OUTERDIMENSIONSIZE> bars` . The std::array class represents a fixed-array, which means you won't be wasting space with it. The internal `vector<Bar>` should provide you with the dynamic inner size you need. It should be accessible like `bars[0][1]`, and you can add as many `Bar` as you need by doing `bars[targetrow].push_back( mybarelement )`

Comment: or a vector of vectors, as in v.size() would give him the inner index, and v[i].size() would give him the outer index. +1 for the effort. Canceling out the -1.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an issue with allocation. The line

```
new vector <Bar*> * [10]
```

will give you an array of points to objects of type `vector <Bar*> *` and you
will need to allocate some additional memory for your `vector <Bar*>` type.

I've had a go,

```
Foo() 
{
    bars = new vector<Bar*>*[10]; // A.

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        bars[i] = new vector<Bar*>;  //  B. Extra memory assigned here.
        bars[i]->push_back(new Bar); //  C.
    }
}
```

To free resources, you'll have to reverse the above

```
~Foo () 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        //  I'm assuming that each vector has one element
        delete bars[i][0]; //  Free C 
        delete bars[i];    //  Free B    
    }

    delete [] bars; // Free A
}
```

Comment: Nice work, you've given a less general explanation then my answer.

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe you're even allocating it properly. To undo what you've done so far, all you'd have to do is:

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
    while(bars[i]->size > 0)
    {
        delete *bars[i]->front();
        pop_front();
    }
delete[] bars;
```

But, you need to allocate each of the vectors themselves, for instance in the constructor:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    bars[i] = new vector<Bar*>();
```

Which would require you change the destructor to:

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    while(bars[i]->size > 0)
    {
        delete *bars[i]->front();
        pop_front();
    }
    delete bars[i];
}
delete[] bars;
```

With regard to your update, I would then suggest changing the type of bars to:

```
vector<Bar*>* bars;
```

and the allocation to (without the need to do the for loop allocation suggested above):

```
bars = new vector<Bar*>[10];
```

Comment: So far, each element has been individually `new`ed.

Comment: This would only get rid of the array of vectors, not the things they point at.

Comment: @chris Yeah, I didn't catch that he was allocating bars.

Comment: Yes, well, his original post was unclear why he wanted vector pointers, so I just played along. As you can see, I suggest later that he just change the type.